# Receiving java.lang.IllegalStateException in my GebConfig

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, automation

Any help would be appreciated. I've read many threads both here, and on other sites, but none have provided me with a solution. I truly can't figure out what is broken in my config.

The full error I'm receiving:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

And here is my config:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver


baseUrl = "mysite.com"

driver = 'chrome'
environments {
    'chrome' {
        def chromeDriver = new File('G:\\Programs\\Eclipse\\Workspace\\chromedriver.exe')
        System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriver.absolutePath)
        driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
        driver.manage().window().maximize()
    }
    'firefox' {
        def FirefoxDriver = new File('G:\\Programs\\Eclipse\\Workspace\\geckodriver.exe')
        System.setProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver', geckoDriver.absolutePath)
        driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    }
}

reportsDir = new File("target/geb-reports1")
```

Both geckodriver and chromedriver are up to date with the latest releases, as are both my browsers. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: I should also note that I've tried updating absolutePath to be `System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', 'G:\\Programs\\Eclipse\\Workspace\\chromedriver.exe')` but unfortunately that hasn't worked, either.

Comment: please check absolutePath documentation. I think it returns only the folder, not the actual chromedriver.exe file. try entering the full absolute path directly on the setProperty method.

Comment: @Sureshmani Unfortunately I've already tried that while troubleshooting. Sorry about that -- I'll update my post